# Migrating Youtube`s video to soundcloud

Tags: youtube-api, soundcloud

Is it possible to migrate youtube`s video to soundcloud?Is there any apis?I want to be able to migrate the video to audio format in soundcloud

Comment: You would need to extract the audio from said YouTube video, and upload the audio to SoundCloud using the Upload API.  What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: javascript ruby @JAL

Comment: i did that one time using a local nodejs proxy to access the iframe and analyse the audio data (i can share the script later when i am home). but be aware thats against the youtube tos - and may be the sc tos as well - copyrights.

Comment: @bnz so it can be done. if possible please send me the link to your demo codes.